# Dynamically created button in table per row in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Only the first row is updating.. I was able to create a dynamically created select tags and button but every time I were to choose to the drop down, only the first row is being updated and the other rows will alert only "choose first" even though i already selected an option.

jquery func'

```
$('input').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr("type")=="button"){
     $(this).click(function{
       var empid=$('#emp').val();
       var job=$('#jobselect').val();
       if(job !== "NULL"){
         $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>userskills/update",
           data:{'Emp_ID':empid,'Job':job},
           cache: false;
           success:
           function(data){
             alert("Updated!");
           }
         });
       }else{
         alert("Choose first");
       }
     });
   }
});
```

this is my tbody in the table

```
<tbody>
  <?php foreach($job as $temp): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $temp->Name?></td>
    <td><?php echo $temp->Group?></td>
    <td><?php echo $temp->Section?></td>
    <td>
     <select id="jobselect">
      <?php foreach($roles as $role): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $role->RoleID">"><?php echo $role->RoleName?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     </select>
     <input type="hidden" id="emp" value="<?php echo $temp->JobID?>" />
     <input type="button" id="update"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique within the document, so your current code creates invalid HTML. The browser won't be too bothered by it and will display your elements anyway, but then in JS if you select by element ID (like `'#jobselect'`) you only get back the *first* element with that ID.

You should switch to use a common `class` instead, and then in your JS use DOM navigation to get from the clicked button (referenced by `this`) to its related controls using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the containing `td` element and then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the items within that `td`:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){ // no need for .each()
   var container = $(this).closest('td');         // 1. get common parent element
   var empid = container.find('.emp').val();      // 2. note the use of .find() with
   var job = container.find('.jobselect').val();  //    class selectors here
   if (job !== "NULL") {
     $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>userskills/update",
       cache: false;
       success:
       function(data){
         alert("Updated!");
       }
     });
   } else {
     alert("Choose first");
   }
});

<tbody>
  <?php foreach($job as $temp): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $temp->Name?></td>
    <td><?php echo $temp->Group?></td>
    <td><?php echo $temp->Section?></td>
    <td>
     <select class="jobselect">
      <?php foreach($roles as $role): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $role->RoleID">"><?php echo $role->RoleName?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     </select>
     <input type="hidden" class="emp" value="<?php echo $temp->JobID?>"
     <input type="button" class="update"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Note that you don't need the `.each()` loop at all if you change your selector to just get the input elements that are buttons.

Comment: its alerting me that it has been updated! But when I check the database, the value is null..

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed that your Ajax was already working, but I see now that it doesn't pass the fields through at all. Add a `data` property to the Ajax options object.

Comment: Its finally okay now.. Arigatou Gozaimasu :)

Comment: Yes, that `$row` was in the original version of my answer, but I fixed in an edit a couple of minutes later (and then edited again to  change the variable name to `container` because I changed it to use the parent td element rather than the parent tr element, though either works).